# server socket 6881 is unable to bind of incoming connection

Tags: vuze

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
    at com.aelitis.azureus.core.networkmanager.impl.tcp.VirtualBlockingServerChannelSelector.start(VirtualBlockingServerChannelSelector.java:77)
    at com.aelitis.azureus.core.networkmanager.impl.tcp.IncomingSocketChannelManager.start(IncomingSocketChannelManager.java:420)
    at com.aelitis.azureus.core.networkmanager.impl.tcp.IncomingSocketChannelManager.<init>(IncomingSocketChannelManager.java:152)
    at com.aelitis.azureus.core.networkmanager.impl.tcp.TCPNetworkManager.<init>(TCPNetworkManager.java:125)
    at com.aelitis.azureus.core.networkmanager.impl.tcp.TCPNetworkManager.<clinit>(TCPNetworkManager.java:48)
    at com.aelitis.azureus.core.networkmanager.NetworkManager.getMinMssSize(NetworkManager.java:267)
    at com.aelitis.azureus.core.networkmanager.impl.ByteBucketST.ensureByteBucketMinBurstRate(ByteBucketST.java:168)
    at com.aelitis.azureus.core.networkmanager.impl.ByteBucketST.<init>(ByteBucketST.java:59)
    at com.aelitis.azureus.core.networkmanager.impl.ByteBucketST.<init>(ByteBucketST.java:45)
    at com.aelitis.azureus.core.networkmanager.impl.TransferProcessor.createBucket(TransferProcessor.java:556)
    at com.aelitis.azureus.core.networkmanager.impl.TransferProcessor.<init>(TransferProcessor.java:75)
    at com.aelitis.azureus.core.networkmanager.NetworkManager.<init>(NetworkManager.java:161)
    at com.aelitis.azureus.core.networkmanager.NetworkManager.<clinit>(NetworkManager.java:53)
    at com.aelitis.azureus.core.impl.AzureusCoreImpl.<init>(AzureusCoreImpl.java:289)
    at com.aelitis.azureus.core.impl.AzureusCoreImpl.create(AzureusCoreImpl.java:145)
    at com.aelitis.azureus.core.AzureusCoreFactory.create(AzureusCoreFactory.java:43)
    at org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main.<init>(Main.java:107)
    at org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main.main(Main.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.aelitis.azureus.launcher.MainExecutor$1.run(MainExecutor.java:34)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
>    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
>    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
>    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
>    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
>    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
> ```

According to error log your on the port your trying to start the application is already in use

before start check for running ports `"netstat -ntlp"` this will show open ports and applications try to use free port.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are having problem with shared network. Go to *Settings >  Network Connections > Properties*, select *Sharing Options* and disable *Allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection*.

Finally restart VUZE, and it's done.